# Multiple node behavior

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, distributed

I had written a code which will pull database rows and process it.
Right now I am selecting 100 rows and making there status as ProcessInprogress and after successful process making status of 100 rows as Processed one by one.
This process is scheduled for every 2 min under quartz.

Question: what I have to take care so that this process can run successfully when my code deployed in multiple nodes. So that I should avoid duplicate data processing in another node.

Please suggest:)

Comment: I'm thinking what if you use select for update, lock those rows down so that the same rows won't be available for usage by another instance of your code.

Comment: Yes with this I can lock records but other process will wait for the lock to release on same records until its time out. I don't think it will go for another next 100 records.

Comment: Hmm. That might be true. Need to find some good way to handle it. Some databases have a way to skip locked records. What database are you using btw?

Comment: Hi.. Sorry for delayed response.. I am using oracle db.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am locking the records fetched by the polling process so that same records should not be fetched by polling process of other instance or node. But this is making other process to wait for release of lock.

Is there anything which I can do so that other process should go to next 100 records fetch instead of waiting on the lock.

Please suggest if any more suggestions for handling behavior of multiple nodes for a database polling process running in java.

Thanks